# chart labels didn't shows in chartjs

Tags: rest, angular, chart.js

I have problem with char labels. I use it like angular call service who get data and chart need to shows in html data. I use last versions of charjs (2.4.0), ng2-charts(1.5.0) angular (2.4.0).

Here is mine code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getStatusChart();
    }

private getStatusChart() {
        this._statisticService.getStatusChart().subscribe( (response) => {
                this.result = response;
                this.doughnutChartDataStatus = this.result.values;
                this.doughnutChartLabelsStatus = ["Open","Assigned","In progress","Complete","Close","Dismiss"];
        });
    }
```

and here is how it's look like:
[image: char]

This is what I get from REST service:

```
data:{labels: ["'Open'", "'Assigned'", "'In progress'", "'Complete'", "'Close'", "'Dismiss'"],
values:[17, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0]}
```

Html template:

```
<div style="display: block">
                            <canvas baseChart
                                    [data]="doughnutChartDataStatus"
                                    [labels]="doughnutChartLabelsStatus"
                                    [chartType]="doughnutChartTypeStatus"
                                    [legend]="doughnutChartLegend"></canvas>
                        </div>
```

If I put labes in setup variable (before constructor, set as local variable), then it works. Can anybody know what is the problem?

Comment: update your post with your HTML template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I move to https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts and thy make it to works perfect! Use it and enjoy ;)